# Remove chapter from ToC without losing the numbering in the document

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I'm trying to remove a chapter in the `ToC` to instead replace it with a custom text.
A easy way is do like this:

```
\chapter*{Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Custom chapter name}
```

But this unfortunately removes all chapter numbers in the 
underlying sections and subsections.

[image]

How can I go around this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, we prefer to have a working document, not just fragments of code! In addition, it might confuse the reader to find different names of chapters in ToC and document

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat cleaner way (in my point of view) to provide a different chapter number title:

Either manipulate the `tocdepth` counter temporarily or use `\chapter[Other ToC Title]{Different in - body - title}`.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A regular chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-5}} % Switch off toc appeareance for a moment
\chapter{In - document chapter name}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Custom chapter name}
\section{Foo}
\blindtext

\chapter[And yet another chapter title in ToC]{And this is the long chapter title that shouldn't appear in ToC!}
\section{Foo bar}
\blindtext[10]


\chapter{Another regular Chapter}
\section{Foo bar bar}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `\refstepcounter{chapter}` as in

```
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\chapter*{Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Custom chapter name}%
```

does the trick.