# Using \autoref with a starred * part, chapter, section in a report

Tags: hyperref, report, autoref, star

I'm writing my thesis in LaTex and I'm having issues with `\autoref`. The issues are illustrated in the MWE below. I included the whole preamble in case there are conflicting packages in it (`hyperref` and `titlesec` don't mix well).

The issue seems to be the `*` in `\chapter*{}` and `\section*{}`. It messes up the numbering in `\autoref{}` even though I added `\addtocounter{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[main=english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}      %font
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{geometry}       % page margins
\geometry{
    left=2.54cm,
    right=2.54cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
}
\headsep = 5mm
\newcommand{\headspace}{\vspace*{-1.5cm}}       % remove headspace on select pages

\makeatletter                           %% Define a HUGE 
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{35}{35}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % headers & footers
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\newcommand{\sbx}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{apacite}            %bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}             %bibliography
\usepackage{bibentry}           %bibliography
\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{\vskip2cm}          % for spacing in between references and list of reference

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}     % package to get the word appendix in the TOC
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter                                                   % for TOC "Part" and spacing
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{1.5em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    {\leavevmode
        \large \bfseries Part #1\hfill\null}\par
    \nobreak
    \global\@nobreaktrue
    \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
    \fi}
\makeatother


\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}} % change name of TOC (doesn't work with titlesec package


\titleclass{\part}{top}                 % formatting part pages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431868/part-page-styling?rq=1)
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\thispagestyle{empty}\raggedleft\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\selectfont\HUGE\bfseries}              %removed page style to get rid of page number on parts, font
{\vspace{8cm}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[.7pt]\vspace{1cm}\Huge}

\titleclass{\chapter}{top}              % formatting chapter pages (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431868/part-page-styling?rq=1)
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\raggedleft\fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\selectfont\HUGE\bfseries}
{\vspace{3pt}{\chaptername} \thechapter}
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pc}\Huge}
%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1.8cm}{1cm}
%

\usepackage[english,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!30!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black},
}
%\newcommand{\link}[1]{{\color{blue!80!black}\href{#1}{#1}}}
%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

%\biboptions{sort&compress}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{darkgray},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray},
}

\usepackage{xparse}                 % to make a signature line
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\signaturelinewidth{5cm}
\newcommand*\signaturelineheight{.4pt}
\newcommand*\signaturedashleaderatom{\kern .1pt.\kern .1pt}
\newcommand*\signaturelineraise{.4ex}
\newcommand*\signaturelabelindent{.5cm}
\newcommand*\signaturetextindent{}
\NewDocumentCommand\signatureline{
    O{\signaturelinewidth}      % line width
    O{\signaturelabelindent}    % label margin
    O{%                           text indentation
        \ifx\@empty\signaturetextindent
        .5\dimexpr #2\relax
        \else
        \signaturetextindent
        \fi
    }
    m                           % label
    O{\signaturelineheight}     % line height
    O{\signaturelineraise}      % line raise
    D||{}                       % text
}{%
    \parbox[t]{#1}{%
        \leftskip #3%
        \mbox{\strut #7}%
        \vskip -#6%
        \hrule height #5%
        \vskip #6%
        \normalsize
        \leftskip #2%
        \rightskip #2%
        \strut #4%
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\signaturedash{
    O{\signaturelinewidth}      % line width
    O{\signaturelabelindent}    % label margin
    O{%                           text indentation
        \ifx\@empty\signaturetextindent
        .5\dimexpr #2\relax
        \else
        \signaturetextindent
        \fi
    }
    m                           % label
    O{\signaturedashleaderatom} % leader atom
    O{\signaturelineraise}      % line raise
    D||{}                       % text
}{%
    \parbox[t]{#1}{%
        \leftskip #3%
        \mbox{\strut #7}%
        \vskip -#6%
        \leftskip 0pt%
        \hrule height 0pt%
        \leavevmode\cleaders\hbox{#5}\hfill\kern 0pt%
        \hrule height 0pt%
        \vskip #6%
        \normalsize
        \leftskip #2%
        \rightskip #2%
        \strut #4%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{afterpage}                                  % command for blank pages
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1 title} \label{part:1}
\chapter{Chapter 1 title}   \label{chap:1}
Reference to \autoref{chap:1}. Correct. 
\chapter{Chapter 2 title}   \label{chap:2}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
Reference to \autoref{chap:2}. Correct. 
\section{Section 1 title}   \label{sec:1}
Reference to \autoref{sec:1}. Correct.

\part*{Part 2 title}    \label{part:2}
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\large Part 2 \vspace{.5em}}{}{}}
\chapter*{Chapter 3 title \\ Why does this repeat?} \label{chap:3}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{Chapter 3}
This is the wrong reference: \autoref{part:2}. It should be part 2.
\chapter*{My super awesome chapter 4}   \label{chap:4}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
This is the wrong reference: \autoref{chap:3}. It should be chapter 3.
\section*{Section 2 title}  \label{sec:2}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
This is the wrong reference: \autoref{sec:2}. It should be section 4.1.

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**
I realized the problem is from using the * in `\chapter*{}`. I don't want the chapters to have a number in the table of contents (which `\chapter*{}` does), but at the same time, be able to be referenced to by `\autoref{}`. So I how do I remove the number from in front of (e.g.) a chapter name when using `\chapter{}`? The TeX documentation says to use * ...

Comment: Untested: maybe `\refstepcounter{part}` instead of `\addtocounter{part}{1}` would work. Also put the `\label` command _after_ the counter update because you want the label to reflect the new counter value. But why do you use unnumbered (starred) parts/chapters when you want to refer to them by number?

Comment: sorry but this all wrong. If you want numbered chapters and section that you can reference then don't use \section*.  Give your readers a change to actually find the referenced section. How should anyone know that "section 4.1" means a section with the title "Section 2 title"?

Comment: @Marijn: because I don't want them to show up in the TOC. Your suggestion worked for part of the `\autoref` inconsistencies, but only for some of them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: your comment isn't helpful. I want to use `\sections*` in some, but not all sections.

Comment: Planting \addtocounter commands everywhere to repair wrong code indicates that something is basically wrong. If you use \section*, only to suppress a toc entry: that is the wrong command.  Use the tocvsec2 package to suppress locally an entry in the toc. Use \section* **only** if you want really an unnumbered section (which then can not be referenced with \ref).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you, that is more informative and helpful!

Comment: I think the problem is more complex that I can explain here.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310399/remove-chapter-from-toc-without-losing-the-numbering-in-the-document